# Which database libraries cooperate with TransactionScope?

Tags: c#, .net, t-sql, enterprise-library

**In general,** is there an interface that indicates `TransactionScope`-awareness? Is there a list of common data libraries that leverage `TransactionScope`? (Is it anything that extends [DbConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbconnection.aspx) or implements [IDbConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idbconnection.aspx)?)

What's the relationship between `TransactionScope` and cooperating data libraries? I.e., does the `TransactionScope` search for active connections in some manner and call the appropriate begin/commit/rollback methods? Does the data library look for ambient `TransactionScope`s? Or both?

**The background**, if necessary. I'm dealing with an old DAL that leverages a few different transaction-like strategies:

```
//
// transactionless queries
//

// Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data. ... 
Database db = SQLHelper.GetDatabase();
DbCommand cmd = db.GetStoredProcComment("doSomething");
db.AddInParameter(cmd, "p1", DbType.Guid, Id);
using (IDataReader r = db.ExecuteReader())
{
  // etc.
}


//
// Transaction objects being passed around and attached to DbCommands
//

// somewhere up the line ... 
DbConnection con = TransactionScopeConnections.GetConnection(db);
DbTransaction transaction = con.BeginTransaction();

// Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data. ... 
Database db = SQLHelper.GetDatabase();
DbConnection con = TransactionScopeConnections.GetConnections(db);
DbCommand cmd = db.GetStoredProcComment("doSomething");
cmd.Transaction = transaction;
db.AddInParameter(cmd, "p1", DbType.Guid, Id);
using (IDataReader r = db.ExecuteReader())
{
  // etc.
}


//
// queries in TransactionScopes
//

using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
{
  // Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data. ... 
  Database db = SQLHelper.GetDatabase();
  DbCommand cmd = db.GetStoredProcComment("doSomething");
  db.AddInParameter(cmd, "p1", DbType.Guid, Id);
  using (IDataReader r = db.ExecuteReader())
  {
    // etc.
  }
  scope.Complete();
}


//
// both
//

Database db = SQLHelper.GetDatabase();
using (TransactionScope transactionScope = new TransactionScope())
{
    DbConnection con = TransactionScopeConnections.GetConnection(db);
    DbTransaction transaction = con.BeginTransaction();

    /* ... build query ... */

    query.transaction = transaction;

    /* ... execute query, read results, if any ... */

    transaction.Commit();
    transactionScope.Complete();

}
```

Are these all valid options with the Enterprise Library? Is the `TransactionScope` form meaningless? Is the last form possibly redundant?

Comment: Why the VTC? If the question isn't clear or is too broad, some constructive feedback, rather than a silent VTC, would be nice! (Actively sorting through an old DAL and trying to understand what's going on!)

Comment: This will have nothing to do with the libraries. It will have to do with what the libraries use underneath. If they use ADO.NET, then you're golden (assuming that the ADO.NET provider called up by your connection string supports TransactionScope).

Comment: @JohnSaunders So, what do I need to look for to see whether these the database and/or connection type returned by the library is compatible? And, what's the nature of the relationship between these objects? I.e., do I need to create the connection and *then* create the transaction? The other way around? Or either order?

Comment: No matter which technologies you wind up using, you'll have to _test_ them. I suggest you get started on that. Like: inside a TransactionScope, use your "library" to do an update, then do not call the `Complete` method. There should be no changes to the database. That will be a big hint. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172152.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question of *Is there an interface that indicates compatibility with TransactionScope? Or a list of Database-type objects that leverage TransactionScope ?*

Yes, you can consider using `IDBTransaction` interface to cover the implementation of .NET framework data providers access relational databases.

The way i see using `TransactionScope` when you would like to promotes transaction into full distributed transaction such as MSDTC. `TransactionScope` itselfs are not restrict to only ADO.NET, you can refer to [Scope and More](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc300805.aspx)

Comment: So, anything that implements `IDBTransaction` will cooperate with `TransactionScope`? ... I've rearrange the question to bring the general question you're answering to the forefront. Do you also know how to answer the question in the 2nd paragraph -- what's the interaction between `TransactionScope` and the cooperating library?